# Is there any difference in the meanings of "Check out this place!" and "Check this place out!"?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, sentence-choice

> Check out this place!
>   Check this place out!

Are the two sentences above both correct? and if so, do they have the exact same meaning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they are both grammatical, and as far as I know they have the same meaning.

I think "Check this place out" is more common for prosodic reasons: it puts a strongly stressed word at the end. "Check out this place" puts emphasis on "this", and suggests "as opposed to [some other] place".

Comment: According to Google Ngrams, your conclusion about frequency is incorrect for general English, although correct for BrE. See my edited answer for a link.

Comment: I don't see any reason for the downvote here.

Comment: Ngrams might not reflect spoken word as well as it does written word.

Answer (score 1):

Both are valid, and reasonably natural, if rather informal. The meanings are essentially the same. The first, with "place" at the end, may emphasize the place a bit more than the other. The second, ending with "out", is more strict;ly informal in usage.

a [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=check+out+this+place%2Ccheck+this+place+out&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccheck%20out%20this%20place%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ccheck%20this%20place%20out%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcheck%20this%20place%20out%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCheck%20this%20place%20out%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ccheck%20out%20this%20place%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ccheck%20this%20place%20out%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcheck%20this%20place%20out%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCheck%20this%20place%20out%3B%2Cc0) shows "check out this place" to be more than twice as frequent as "check this place out" in their collection of texts. However, in the "British" sub-collection, only the phrase "check this place out" occurs at all.

Comment: The GloWbE corpus disagrees. "Check out this place" has 13 instances (3 each frrom US and Singapore, 2 from Canada, and a few 1s). "Check this place out" has 60 ( 14 US, 8 Canada, 7 Australlia, 4-6 Far Eastern Englishes, 3 UK). I think the numbers are too small to conclude anything - unsurprising, since this is far less likely to be written than spoken. Google Ngrams is presumably from conversations in books.